# pandas to calculate rolling sum for each group with condition based on another column

Tags: pandas

I have a data set like below

```
data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'ID':[1,1,1,1, 1, 1,2,2],
    'Date': ['2020-01-10', '2020-01-10', '2020-02-01', '2020-03-01', '2020-09-01', '2020-10-01',
          '2020-01-01', '2020-09-15'],
    'Dollar': [5, 10,25,30,15,12,9,7],
    }     
    )

data.head(10)
```

I would like to calculate the sum of 'Dollar' by each 'ID' but conditionally based on 'Date' within the past 2 months without the 'Dollar' from the current record. The results expect to be like below:

[image]

I know one way could be

1. fill up all the 'Date' between records for each 'ID'
2. assign 'Dollar'to 0 for these filled months
3. take shift(1) by each 'ID' for the 'Dollar'
4. use the rolling(2).sum() for each 'ID'
5. join back on 'ID' and 'Date'

Is there any easy way to do that?

Or another way is to use the data set to join with itself then filtering before take the rolling sum